# Does Windows Server have temp folder limits?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I work as PHP developer in a small enterprise. We have a cloud server with Windows Server 2012 where we host our projects that are still awaiting approval.

Early today, a client called us and told us he could not upload files to the server and it was returning error code 6.

The temp folder was set as C:\Windows\Temp. The permissions were correct. I didn't understand what was happening, so I checked the folder. It had 64GB of temporary files (a round number, this aroused my curiosity). Then I cleaned the folder and the problem was resolved.

I always thought that Windows folders have no size limits. I could not find anything about this limit on the internet. What could have happened?

Comment: How much free disk space was there before you deleted the files?

Comment: @joeqwerty disk space was not a problem. I have more than 500gb free.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Server has [Quota Management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733029(v=ws.11).aspx):

> On the Quota Management node of the File Server Resource Manager
>   Microsoft® Management Console (MMC) snap-in, you can perform the
>   following tasks:
>
> - Create quotas to limit the space allowed for a volume or folder, and generate notifications when the quota limits are approached or
>     exceeded.
> - Generate auto apply quotas that apply to all existing subfolders in a volume or folder and to any subfolders that are created in the
>     future.
> - Define quota templates that can be easily applied to new volumes or folders and then used across an organization.

More generally, [Disk Quotas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938945.aspx) is a feature of the NTFS filesystem:

> Disk quotas are tracked on a per-user, per-volume basis; users are
>   charged only for the files they own. Quotas are tracked per volume,
>   even if the volumes are different partitions on the same physical hard
>   disk.

It is also possible to [Assign a mount point folder path to a drive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321(v=ws.11).aspx), instead of the usual drive letter. I've used this in similar scenario, where a log folder or a print spooler can't fill up whole `C:` and limitations in the software only allows hardcoded paths to the system drive. This would cause the folder to have different limit as it would be on a separate drive.

Or then the third and the most obvious option: the drive was full.

Comment: I did not know about Quota Management. I'm responsible just for maintain the projects running. I will ask about it with the one who administer the server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> To manage folder quotas, you must use the File Server Resource Manager
>   (FSRM) Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in. From the FSRM, you
>   can perform the following tasks:
>
> - Create quotas to limit the space that is allowed for a volume or    folder, and 
>           generate notifications when the quota limits are approached or exceeded.
> - Generate quotas that automatically apply to all existing subfolders    in a volume or folder and to any subfolders that are created in the
>     future.
> - Define quota templates that can be easily applied to new volumes or    folders and then used across an organization.
>
> For example, you can:
>
> - Place a 200 megabyte (MB) limit on users' personal server folders,    and generate a notification to you and the user when 180 MB of
>     storage has been exceeded.
> - Set a flexible 500 MB quota on a group's shared folder. When this    storage limit is reached, all users in the group are notified by
>     e-mail that the storage quota has been temporarily extended to 520 MB 
>     so that they can delete unnecessary files and comply with the preset
>     500 MB quota policy.
> - Receive a notification when a temporary folder reaches 2 gigabytes    (GB) of usage, yet not limit that folder's quota because it is
>     necessary for a service that is running on your server.

Here is the link to this information - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875785(v=ws.10).aspx